# How can i fill a table from another table with same column path

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm trying to insert data into a table from an existing table with this schema :

```
X1 | Y1 | Z1 | X2 | Y2 | Z2
---------------------------
a  | 1  |  2 |  c |  5 |  6
b  | 3  |  4 |  d |  7 |  8
```

And the table that i want to fill should have this schema :

```
X  | Y  | Z
--------------
a  | 1  |  2   
b  | 3  |  4  
c  | 5  |  6
d  | 7  |  8
```

How should i do for do that, if it is possible.

Thanks in advance for your reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a lateral join:

```
select v.x, v.y, v.z
from t cross join lateral
     (values (t.X1, t.Y1, t.Z1), (t.X2, t.Y2, t.Z2)) v(x, y, z);
```

This should have better performance than `union all`, because it scans the database only once.

Answer (score 1):

Use these 2 insert statements:

```
INSERT INTO t2 (X, Y, Z) 
SELECT X1, Y1, Z1 
FROM t1;
INSERT INTO t2 (X, Y, Z) 
SELECT X2, Y2, Z2 
FROM t1;
```

replace `t1` and `t2` with the names of the source and the destination table.  
 I believe the above code is easy to understand.

 **Edit** or in 1 union statement

```
INSERT INTO t2 (X, Y, Z) 
SELECT X1, Y1, Z1 
FROM t1
UNION
SELECT X2, Y2, Z2 
FROM t1;
```

Comment: if i have 10 column with same path (X1,Y1,Z1,...., X10,Y10,Z10), there is a quickest way

Comment: See my edited answer, still I believe the multiple inserts are cleaner.

Comment: Thanks, but i was searching something that operate in automatic, like a for or while

Comment: A for or a while is for sure not faster than a simple insert statement.

Answer (score 0):

You may do a dynamic insertion by constructing the sql select query from getting the column information from the catalog.

```
DO $body$
DECLARE l_select TEXT;
        l_tabname text := 'yourtab';
  BEGIN 
   SELECT string_agg('SELECT ' 
                || cols 
                || ' FROM ' 
                || table_name,' UNION ALL ') 
   INTO   l_select 
   FROM   ( 
                  SELECT   table_name, 
                           String_agg(column_name,',') cols 
                  FROM     information_schema.columns 
                  WHERE    table_name = l_tabname 
                  GROUP BY table_name, 
                           substr(column_name,2) )s; 

  EXECUTE 'INSERT  INTO yourtab2 (X, Y, Z) ' || l_select ; 
  END
 $body$;
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=170f29eea3a02cbe7cdb7252cedd02bf)